# How to get URN of members/organizations for LinkedIn Mentions

Tags: linkedin-api, mention

How can I implement a mention without knowing the URN of a member/organization on a LinkedIn UGC post. Documentation states that you need to provide the URN of the member / organization you are mentioning. Is there anyone who have implemented LinkedIn mentions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am trying to follow this documentation: #https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-access-control#find-organization-access-control
 and cannot find within the Linkedin UI what my URN is

Comment: Let us know if you manage to solve this